# Are special condition identifiers (e.g. AIG+) standardized?

Tags: trading

Suffixes indicating class, preferred, new, etc., are well defined for NASDAQ and NYSE, but I can't find anything documenting the meanings of the trailing punctuation. For example, here's some that I saw in today's feed from NASDAQ:

- OHI-D*
- REN+
- RTN+
- SGS=
- F+
- AIG+
- BLL#
- AA-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is the Nasdaq Ticker Symbol conventions for CQS securities. You can essentially translate them at the below link:

http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=CQSSymbolConvention